# Black frames at beginning of video file when file cut

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, cut

I use ffmpeg to cut a video file.
The format i use is this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:06:30 -to 00:07:15 -c copy output.avi
```

Unfortunately this leaves some black frames in the beginning of my output video, so i lose certain parts of the video. In one video i tried, this went on for one second, in another, the black frames lasted 4 seconds.

The funny thing is that when i used the same command, exactly the same amount of black frame exists for the same video. Meaning, no matter how many times i did this for my second video, in all outputs, the output video will be blank for the first 4 seconds!

The sound works great though!

Here are some other command formats i tried and did NOT work:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy -copyts cut.mp4
```

I thout i found my solution with the command i used, but then this problem occured

EDIT: I figured out that if i don't use the `-c copy`  flag, then i do not have the black frames:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:06:30 -to 00:07:15 output.avi
```

However, with this method, the quality of my output video is significantly lower than the input video, or the output video from the previous methods. So i am back at square one.

Comment: "Unfortunately this leaves some black frames in the beginning of my output video" – how are you trying to view the video? Also, please show the full, uncut command line output as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you are using a recent version of ffmpeg by [downloading a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), for example. There have been some major changes a while ago which affect how stream cutting works.

Here's the important difference between the commands that you ran:

- When specifying `-c copy`, ffmpeg will cut the video without modifying the actual bitstream. In other words, it will take the frames as-is and copy them to the output file. In some cases (simply put, when the starting time does not correspond to an [I-frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intra-frame_coding)), ffmpeg needs to include some more frames that are needed to properly decode the first frame to be displayed. Those will get a negative timestamp, so they shouldn't be shown.
- When you leave out `-c copy`, ffmpeg will re-encode the video with whatever encoder (`mpeg4`, `libx264`, ...) is the default for the chosen output format (AVI or MP4 in your case). These encoders may have default quality or bitrate settings that make the output look bad. When re-encoding, you should therefore know what target quality you want to set.

If cutting with stream copying does not work for you, and if you have to re-encode the video, you may as well use a recent and efficient video codec (H.264) and container (MP4), and copy the audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:45 -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -to 00:11:45 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Here, the CRF option controls the output quality. Values between 18 and 28 are "normal", lower values are better. The `-ss` option can be an input option (i.e., one that appears before `-i`) which makes everything faster.

For more information, read the [Seeking guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) on the FFmpeg Wiki.

Comment: What do you mean by "the `-ss` can be an input option" here?

Comment: @Hashim See updated post

Comment: Using `https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg` i warnt able to use `libx264` because it couldn't be found. Worked when using `mpeg4`

Comment: @Smogen mpeg4 is not very efficient and quite outdated. You apparently compiled mobile-ffmpeg without support for libx264. The project supports it, you have to manually compile it.

Comment: I use `implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.LTS'` in my grade dependencies, using ffmpeg in my android app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Is it not possible to just re-encode the parts at the start/end so the stop/start time specified is what is used. I dont want to re-encode every thing as my machine is old and does it at less than 0.5 rate so it takes forever. I also do not want to remove those frames as the audio will still be there and result in A&V out of sync.  if i try to cut out the 5 minutes of a video using the following command i get an extra few seconds at the start. ffmpeg -ss 00:06:00 -to 00:11:00 -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy output.mp4 moving to 06:01 still results in the same.

Comment: @Grimeire Not easily doable. You would have to exactly match the previous encoding settings and find stitching points at intra-frames, then paste together the bitstreams. I would recommend against it and just encoding it at the slow pace.

Comment: @slhck thanks thats what i though. I was hoping i was missing something and there was an easy way. I guess i'll just leave the extra few seconds in each video.

Answer (score 0):

it's about the order of `-ss` and `-t`, here's what I figured out

```shell
# has black frames
ffmpeg -i input.MOV -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -c copy output1.mp4

# works, no black frame
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -i input.MOV -c copy output2.mp4
```

original answer can be found [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/25633/30149)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having the same problem, i finally managed to solve it with this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -qscale 0 -ss 00:10:45 -to 00:11:45 output.avi
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem you're experiencing. it is **not recommended**. Here you are re-encoding the video and creating an unnecessarily large output file while doing so.